# How to avoid C++ undefined behavior fooling GoogleTest

Tags: c++, googletest, undefined-behavior

I'm writing tests for my container class, and many of those tests check query methods, which return `true` or `false`. Example:

```
myContainer.add(obj);
EXPECT_TRUE(myContainer.contains(obj));
```

The problem is that many of those tests pass even without a `MyContainer` implementation.

I **think** that I already found what is the cause of this, and it is demonstrated below (problem is that `RealityTest.Sneaky` passes):

```
TEST(RealityTest, True) {
  bool b = true;
  EXPECT_TRUE(b);
  EXPECT_FALSE(b);
}
TEST(RealityTest, False) {
  bool b = false;
  EXPECT_TRUE(b);
  EXPECT_FALSE(b);
}
TEST(RealityTest, RandomBool) {
  bool b = random_bool();
  EXPECT_TRUE(b);
  EXPECT_FALSE(b);
}
TEST(RealityTest, Sneaky) {
  bool b = sneaky();
  EXPECT_TRUE(b);
  EXPECT_FALSE(b);
}
TEST(RealityTest, NoBool) {
  bool b = no_bool();
  EXPECT_TRUE(b);
  EXPECT_FALSE(b);
}
```

With functions used in tests defined like this:

```
bool random_bool() {
  static std::random_device dev;
  static std::uniform_int_distribution dist(0, 1);
  return dist(dev);
};

bool sneaky() { cout << "brought to you by GCC (C++17)" << endl; }

bool no_bool() {}
```

How should I write tests so that this "sneaky" mechanism can't fool them because as of right now, if I were to implement only things like `MyContainer::add`, `MyContainer::get` and `MyContainer::remove` then all my tests would pass despite the fact that all those query methods are not working.

Note: I build everything (tests and `MyContainer`) without any compiler optimizations (Debug mode in Qt Creator).

Note 2: I use Qt Creator but not any of Qt modules/libs. Just plain C++17 with `googletest` and `pthread` (I'm on Linux).

Comment: 1. Turn on and listen to (by e.g. upgrading to errors) the compiler warnings, 2. don't rely on unit tests to find UB, that's not what they are for. UB can _by definition_ fool your unit tests.

Comment: You build with `-Werror`, and these tests fail because your project *doesn't build*.

Comment: While you could shown an image of the test results, please don't show images of code, or text in general.

Comment: Ok... I admit that for some weird reason -Werror did not crossed my mind. Thanks for that, I'm going to use it for sure :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compiler should **warn** you that there are paths in your function that do not return a value. If it does not, increase your **warning level** (e.g. `-Wall` and/or `-Wextra`) and make sure those warnings are not supressed.

In case you (or your coworkers) are prone to ignoring those warnings, use [`-Werror`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) to turn them (well, *all* warnings) into compile errors - this way your project won't *compile* if there are things that trip those warnings, e.g. having a path that doesn't return a value.

That said, GoogleTest **can't** help you find those errors - it only works with the compiled objects, so it can't tell your `bool sneaky()` function doesn't have a proper return value... Remember: [Undefined behavior can result in time travel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633).. or allow [b to be TRUE and FALSE at the same time](https://markshroyer.com/2012/06/c-both-true-and-false/)